# Cannot assign type in http.get angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, get

Hi I have a service with the next method:

```
  getOcpiEquiposParaComandos(): Observable<EquipoComandos[]> {
    return this.http.get<EquipoComandos[]>(environment.uri + "/getOcpiEquiposParaComandos", this.options);
  }
```

But the compiler return me the next error:

```
Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<EquipoComandos[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<EquipoComandos[]>'.
```

As u can see I tried to assign the type `EquipoComandos[]` to the http.get response but compiler force me to use the next declaration:

```
  getOcpiEquiposParaComandos(): Observable<HttpEvent<EquipoComandos[]>> {
    return this.http.get<EquipoComandos[]>(environment.uri + "/getOcpiEquiposParaComandos", this.options);
  }
```

But then I cant use forEach normally:

```
Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<EquipoComandos[]>'.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do  you subscribe to the observable?

Comment: @Zer0 Yes, the original declaration use <any> as return of the HTTP.get and my app works fine. I only try to add types to my http.gets

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 getOcpiEquiposParaComandos(): Observable<EquipoComandos[]> {
    return this.http.get<EquipoComandos[]>(environment.uri + "/getOcpiEquiposParaComandos", this.options);
  }
```

You had the return type of your method wrapped in an HttpEvent this is not needed. The HttpClient will transform the response json to your type. You should also subscribe to get the values out of your `Observable<EquipoComandos[]>`

like this:

```
paraComandosService.getOcpiEquiposParaComandos().subscribe(x=>
    x.foreach(x=> console.log(x))
)
```

Comment: As I say, the compiler don't allow me to use the declaration you mention, I worked the question for being more clear.